# How to apply GridSearch on a RidgeCV model

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I want to apply `GridSearchCV` on `RidgeCV Regression`. Given that the `alphas` parameter is an array, how can I include it in the grid? The way I am doing it below is wrong and I know it, but how could I correct it?

`model_1=MultiOutputRegressor(RidgeCV(), n_jobs=-1)
search_grid={'estimator__cv':[3,4,5,6,7], 'estimator__alphas':list(x / 10 for x in range(0, 101))}
search= GridSearchCV(model_1, search_grid, n_jobs=-1, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', verbose=4)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem. As far as I can see the way you are reading in the alphas, is not the problem. I suspect that since you are using [sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html?highlight=multioutputregressor#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor) and inside of it the [RidgeCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV)-Classifier a problem with how you call `'estimator__cv'` and `'estimator__alphas'` occurs. You might need to either go into the RidgeCV with a double step like `'model1__estimator__cv'` and `'model1__estimator__alphas'` or you will have to go about it in another way. Like:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
pipeline = Pipeline([('clf'=RidgeCV())])#[Pipeline][3]is not necessary but my personal preference
search_grid={'clf__cv':[3,4,5,6,7], 'clf__alphas':list(x / 10 for x in range(0, 101))}
search= GridSearchCV(pipeline, search_grid, n_jobs=-1, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', verbose=4)
gs_fit= search.fit(x_train, y_train)
optimal_parameters = gs_fit.best_params_
print(optimal_parameters)
```

Then use the optimal estimators in your MultiOutputRegression in a seperate step. Even though not in one run, this would give you the results you were looking for.